# Storing a file in Google Drive using download link

Tags: google-drive, upload

I want to upload a file in google drive using the download link; in fact I want google to download my file and store it to its drive.
I've search the web but no way except downloading the file, then uploading using the upload file button in the drive. 
Could you please help me to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -2):

I'm answering my own question :)
I've found a third party app that is doing this job perfectly! the app is

[Copy, URL to Google Drive](https://softgateon.herokuapp.com)

You can find this app using the more apps buttons when you click add files or folder.

wishing you the best!

Comment: The links is not working